# trying to figure out generics and could not comprehend what <num> means in this code

Tags: dart

Trying to lean dart generics and i have come across the following code

```
var data = Future<num>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    return 2;
  });
```

i want to know what num represents

Answer (score 0):

Future takes a type parameter `T`, i.e., the return value of the `Future`, which is a num in your example.

`num` is an integer or floating-point number.

Take a look at the [docs for the `num` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/num-class.html) and the [`Future<T>` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-async/Future-class.html).

Comment: ok but what i meant is what does it signify like Future only takes numbers?

Comment: Well, `Future<T>` takes a type parameter `T`: the return value of the Future, which is a `num` in your example.